# Bug in hibernate 5 insert sequence order

Tags: java, hibernate, migration

### The structure

We have the following **entity** classes:

1:

```
class GlobalUnit
```

2:

```
class Fleet extends GlobalUnit

@ManyToOne
City city;
```

This means in terms of hibernate relationships City is a parent entity for Fleet and Fleet is a child entity for City.

3:

```
class City extends GlobalUnit
```

4:

```
class SpawningPoint extends GlobalUnit

@OneToOne
Beast beast;
```

5:

```
class Beast
```

In terms of hibernate relationships Beast is a parent entity for Spawning point therefore should be inserted before SpawningPoint.

### The problem

We have a transaction when we generate a world and push a pack of cities, beasts and fleets into the database.
The transaction crashes with constraint violation exception because:

-- Before executing inserts hibernate sorts the insert batches wrong, because:

-- In `org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue` class, method `sort`, line `if (prevBatchIdentifier.hasAnyParentEntityNames(batchIdentifier)) {` returns `true` when prevBatchIdentifier is `Fleet` and batchIdentifier is `SpawningPoint`, because:

-- hasAnyParentEntityNames checks `parentEntityNames` of `Fleet` and there is a `GlobalUnit` istead of `City`. (**which is wrong**) And because root entity name of `SpawningPoint` is `GlobalUnit` the method thinks the SpawningPoint is a **parent** of the Fleet depsite they have no relationships at all, the method returns true, which leads to wrong switching of the SpawningPoint insert batch and Fleet insert batch, which leads to the crash.

Here the order of batches before sort: (which should work)

- 0 City
- 1 SpawningPoint
- 2 Fleet
- 3 Beast

First step of sorting moves SpawningPoint up to be inserted after Beast (which is correct)

- 0 City
- 1 Fleet
- 2 Beast
- 3 SpawningPoint

Second step of sorting moves SpawningPoint down because of Fleet. Fleet has SpawningPoint in its parents (which is wrong as described above)

- 0 City
- 1 SpawningPoint
- 2 Fleet
- 3 Beast

This causes crash because SpawningPoint can't be inserted before Beast.

the list of parents is stored in `ClassMetadata`:

```
ClassMetadata classMetadata = action.getPersister().getClassMetadata();
Type[] propertyTypes = classMetadata.getPropertyTypes();
```

Please note:
The same code worked fine in hibernate 4 and the problem appeared when we moved to hibernate 5.

### The questions:

1. Why does hibernate store root entity in parent types instead of real entity which takes part in the relationship?
2. How can I fix my problem?

   TIA!

### Update:

I used a workaround: GlobalUnit mapping changed from `@Entity` to `@MappedSuperClass`. The sorting works correct in this case, but we are not able to get entity using `session.get(GlobalUnit.class)` anymore so we had to use ugly switches to get entities of Fleet, City and SpawningPoint depending on the object type, despite in many places we don't need concrete classes and `GlobalUnit` would be enough.